# List products that almost matches the search query even when there is spelling mistake

Tags: php, mysql, search

Am trying to code a simple PHP with MySQL website. I will list some simple products. But for the site wide SEARCH, I wanted to do something that will fetch the results even if there's a small typo in the search terms. Say for example, if user searches for "nkia" instead of "nokia", it should list out the "nokia" products in the search results.

Something like the search functionality in flipkart.com is what I have in my mind. So, how could we do that?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198109/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-typo-correction-into-a-search-in-php-mysql

Comment: https://www.google.hu/search?q=spell+correction+php a LOT of duplicates

Comment: Look up Levenshtein distance.  Or use a text search engine that supports a thesaurus.

Comment: Thank you will do some research on that